# Spring MVC and MustacheViewResolver character encoding issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mustache

I'm trying Mustache View Resolver with Spring MVC, but in my Html view, im getting character encoding issue. I tried many solutions to solve this problem but couldnt handle this.

I have an basic ArrayList model, Mustache resolves Turkish characters correctly but outside of templated words, makes no sense.

You can access to my project under Github

https://github.com/rahmanusta/SpringMvcMustache

Answer (score 0):

I see you added a section to configure the `maven-compiler-plugin` in your `pom.xml`, and you have UTF-8 characters in your Java source code files.
I guess the text from your java scource files are not displaying correctly. If that is the case, telling the compiler plugin explicitely which encoding to use might help:

```
<build>
    <finalName>MvcMustache</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <!-- fetch encoding from definition up in the pom.xml -->
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I changed my app with your suggestion, but, nothing changed Clemens

Comment: Ok, then at least we know this is not the problem.  Sorry that it did not work.

Comment: I added to VM parameter, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, it solved the problem, thanks Clemens.